# change color after every four divs angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am devolping a mobile app using angular js and ionic. I have problem for changing the color of divs.I want different colors of each div and that colors repeats after every four divs.

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="card">
        <div class="custom_row">
        <div class="col-32-custom"  ng-repeat="services in services_data track by $index">


        <div ng-if="($index+1)%2==0"class="brand-content wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 700ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: fadeIn;">
        <div class="service_cover" style="
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
">
                                <img class="pull-left img-responsive bright" src="http://incitysearch.com/themes/web/images/app/{{services.icons}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body" style="padding-bottom:25px;">                           
                                    <h2 class="align_center">{{services.name}}</h2>
                        <p class="align_center_des">{{services.description}}</p>                                            
                                       <a href="#job/{{services.id}}">
                                 <span class="select_btn ">

                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{services.name}}" class="btn btn-submit service " style="opacity:0;"  />
                                    <label for="radio1" style="color:white;margin-left:-5px;"><span><span></span></span>Select</label></a></span>




                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div ng-if="($index+1)%2!=0"class="brand-content wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 700ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: fadeIn;background-color:black;">
        <div class="service_cover" style="
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
">
                                <img class="pull-left img-responsive bright" src="http://incitysearch.com/themes/web/images/app/{{services.icons}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body" style="padding-bottom:25px;">                           
                                    <h2 class="align_center">{{services.name}}</h2>
                        <p class="align_center_des">{{services.description}}</p>                                            
                                       <a href="#job/{{services.id}}">
                                 <span class="select_btn ">

                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{services.name}}" class="btn btn-submit service " style="opacity:0;"  />
                                    <label for="radio1" style="color:white;margin-left:-5px;"><span><span></span></span>Select</label></a></span>




                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t8666av0/

Comment: You can try using ng-if directive with the condition "num%4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ng-class` to change the css class based in the value of `$index`. Something like this going off the top of my head. This should point you in the correct direction at least.

```
ng-class="{'0': 'blue', '1': 'red', '2': 'green', '3': 'yellow'}[$index % 4]"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about CSS? Much simple for You. e.g:

```
.your-class:nth-child(4){
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```